# DataMapper, when to call finalize

Tags: datamapper

If I have this program.

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'

DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
DataMapper.setup(:default, “sqlite3:///#{Dir.pwd}mydb.sqlite”)

class MyClass
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,   Serial
  property :column1, String, :required => true
end
DataMapper.auto_migrate!

class MyClass
  property :column2, String
end
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

It will run and create a table `myclasses` and then update the table.
Does that mean I don't need to call `DataMapper.finalize`?

If I need to call, where should I call it?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html), `.finalize` :

> checks the models for validity and initializes all properties associated with relationships

So I tend to use it immediately after `auto_upgrade!` or `auto_migrate` because these are the migrations that actually change the content of your database, so after these you should use `finalize` to make sure that all the properties' (columns) updates are modified in the database.